# Line numbers in all emacs buffers

Tags: emacs

I want to make that would in all the buffers which I had opened were line numbers in GNU/Emacs. In my .emacs i try to add:

```
(linum-mode t)
```

but it's not helped me.

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try with that in your `.emacs`:

```
(require 'linum)
(global-linum-mode)
```

Comment: There's a typo, you should have :

(require 'linum)
(global-linum-mode)

Comment: You can get rid of the "require": global-linum-mode is autoloaded

Answer (score 3):

You can also customize the line number format, using printf style formatting.

eg. `%5d` for 5 char padding.

<kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> `customize-group` <kbd>RET</kbd> `linum` <kbd>RET</kbd> for all the options.